# Algebra of a cartesian product of two or more copies of a Lie Group

Tags: lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie Group end let us consider the Cartesian product of $n$ copies of $G$ ($N\geq 2$): $G\times G\times \ldots \times G$.
What is the Lie Algebra of this group?
Is the Lie Algebra the direct sum **g**+**g**...+**g** (where **g** is the Lie algebra of $G$) ?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is.

Generally, when $M_1,\ldots,M_n$ are manifolds and for every $i$, $p_i\in M_i$ we have the identity $$T_{(p_1,\ldots,p_n)}M_1\times\ldots\times M_n=\bigoplus_iT_{p_i}M_i.$$Now given a Lie group $G$, its Lie algebra can be identified with $T_eG$, and we're done.

Comment: You need to know that this identification is natural in order to know that it respects the Lie bracket; a priori this argument only tells you that you get an identification as vector spaces.